# Хочется мн. ч. при согласовании сказуемого с подлежащим "большинство", возможно ли в моём случае?

Tags: согласование, собирательное-существительное

> Большинство знакомо между собой, включая прохожих, оттого над улицей
> стоит оживлённый гул.

**[Сказуемое во множественном числе обычно употребляется в таких случаях:](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/783-33_nekotorye_osobennosti_soglasovaniya.html)**

а) между подлежащим и сказуемым есть другие члены предложения, особенно причастный оборот с причастием во множественном числе, придаточное предложение с союзным словом который во множественном числе. (Хотя это правило не носит обязательного характера, всё же желательно использовать в таких конструкциях именно форму множественного числа сказуемого.)

*Большинство людей, смотревших фильм, высоко оценили работу режиссера; Большинство людей, которые смотрели фильм, высоко оценили работу режиссера;*

б) при существительном есть несколько управляемых форм во множественном числе:

*Большинство рабочих, инженеров и служащих завода поддержали директора;*

в) при подлежащем есть однородные сказуемые:

*Большинство студентов сдали зачёты и хорошо подготовились к экзаменам;*

г) в предложении используется составное именное сказуемое, причём именная часть выражена прилагательными и причастиями:

*Большинство детей были нарядны и веселы; Большинство домов на этой улице деревянные.*

---

***Для постановки сказуемого во множественное число необходимо действие дополнительных факторов. Например, наиболее распространённой является форма множественного числа сказуемого при подлежащем, указывающем на одушевлённые предметы, прежде всего – на людей.***

---

Мне ничего не подойдёт? Оставить "знакомо"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Постановка сказуемого в форме множественного числа может быть продиктована **условиями контекста или стилистическим заданием,** например: **На конгресс славистов прибыло много гостей; задолго до заседания большинство заняли отведенные для них места (форма заняли находится в соответствии с последующей формой множественного числа для них);** Проценко вполне отчетливо представлял себе, что большинство, очевидно, умрут здесь... (Симонов).

**Розенталь. Д.Э.**

В вашем случае предлог "между" указывает на группу лиц, здесь важно учитывать и слово "прохожих", которое стоит во мн.ч.

Ср., напр: **Большинство знакомо с законом; Большинство знакомо с его поэтическими произведениями.**

В этих примерах ед.ч. обусловлено тем, что собирательное существительное не имеет при себе зависимых слов.

Comment: Думаю, что учесть "прохожих" здесь _недостаточно_, поскольку это слово употребляется позже и грамматически отвязано от "большинства" (не является зависимым словом по отношению к нему). В случае же с пресловутым Проценко, вероятно, решил предшествующий **контекст** - надо искать текст произведения (это трудно, поскольку по сети обильно разбросана эта отдельная фраза).

Comment: Включая прохожих, т. е.  знакомы были и прохожие. К тому же, как я уже отметил, есть предлог "между".

Comment: С предлогом - согласен, он разбивает большинство на подразумеваемых индивидов, находясь в рамках общей конструкции (грамматически привязано к тому самому глаголу). "Прохожие" в этом смысле - слово постороннее, из оборота, стоящего _после_ самодостаточного предложения. В предшествующем же контексте это слово могло бы "сработать".

Answer (score 4):

Перед употреблением просто "большинства" или вместе с ним (соответственно, в предш. предложении или в том же) нужна конкретная привязка этого слова (кого/чего), поскольку множественное число глагола управляется зависимым словом, а не самим "большинством". Например:

> a) ... *жители* села Степанчиково. Большинство знакомы между собой, включая прохожих...
>
> б) Большинство *сельчан* знакомы между собой, включая прохожих...

Answer (score 0):

**Большинство знакомо** между собой, включая прохожих, оттого над улицей стоит оживлённый гул.

Обоснование: 1) нет зависимых слов у существительного *большинство*; 2) сказуемое следует сразу за подлежащим, поэтому желательно согласование в одном числе.

Розенталь: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm

Сказуемое ставится в единственном числе, если собирательное существительное **не имеет при себе управляемых слов**, например **большинство голосовало** за предложенную резолюцию, меньшинство было против.

Исключения: Постановка сказуемого в форме множественного числа в этом случае может быть продиктована условиями контекста или стилистическим заданием, например: На конгресс славистов прибыло много гостей; задолго до заседания большинство заняли отведенные **для них** места (форма заняли находится в соответствии с последующей формой множественного числа для них); Проценко вполне отчетливо представлял себе, что **большинство,** очевидно, **умрут** здесь... (Симонов).